# How to create an Hours of Operation list with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly create a list for hours of operations using basic html and css.

I trying to make 2 columns. On the left column is the day of the week (`text-align:right;`) and on the right is the Hours (`text-align:left;`) so that the right edge of the day and the left edge of the hours is aligned in the center.

Is there a way to do this and keeping the 2 list items aligned to the center?

Can this be done with a `<dl>` or 2 `<ul>` ?

here is a visual [Example](http://screencast.com/t/ClyGI7Oqp)

Right:

```
   Sunday: Closed
   Monday: 9am - 5pm
  Tuesday: 9am - 5pm
Wednesday: 9am - 5pm
 Thursday: 9am - 5pm
```

Wrong:

```
Sunday: Closed
Monday: 9am - 5pm
Tuesday: 9am - 5pm
Wednesday: 9am - 5pm
Thursday: 9am - 5pm
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a normal `<table>` element for this. Since your data is actually a table, there is no shame in using it here. Alternatively a `dl` could be valid too.

```css
th {
  text-align: right; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Sunday</th><td>Closed</td></tr>
<tr><th>Monday</th><td>9am - 5pm</td></tr>
<tr><th>Tuesday</th><td>9am - 5pm</td></tr>
<tr><th>Wednesday</th><td>9am - 5pm</td></tr>
<tr><th>Thursday</th><td>9am - 5pm</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Haha my school told me to never use tables for layout but I suppose this would be a valid time to use a table! Thank you!

Comment: Not for layout, that's true. But table data can still be in tables. A spreadsheet  or calendar, or address list is an obvious choice. This list of opening hours is maybe a grey area, but I think it's perfectly fine.